# In JS receive information from a json file

Tags: javascript, browser

In node.js in order to get information out of a .json file you would need to use the `require` function.

I am making an Artificial Neural Network which is using this code in order to get the data from the data.json file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json'));
console.log(brain.likely(json, net));
```

How would you adapt this code in order to make it run in the browser environment?

Comment: *Generally*, you'd access that file over the network. Likely using AJAX or perhaps using websockets. It depends on how the server you're trying to get the file from is set up.

Comment: Reading a file wouldn't really work in the browser environment, since a browser accessing the local file system isn't really a thing yet (although it's being worked on, I think). You'd need to serve the file in a server, and get the file through an HTTP call from the browser (client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Fetch API.

It is documented here at MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Hope this will help.